# How to handle different File System passthrough for Windows VM

Tags: partition, windows, kvm, volume

I would like to know which options I have to handle a more advanced file system and volume manager like ZFS or LVM+XFS with KVM and windows.

Should I create a LVM volume-group and passthrough it to the windows VM, can windows create its own 'partitions' inside a volume group?
Or would this work with a zpool?

Or do I need to emulate a volume-group/zpool as a single drive? This would have an impact on i/o performance

Or should I do this entirely different?

(I do not want to install the windows vm inside a file)

Comment: Are you trying to install Windows *natively* on these file systems?

Comment: @ajgringo619 Yes exatcly, I would like to install windows directly (natively) on a partition handled by ZFS/LVM. (I use a m.2 ssd)

Comment: I guess you can try pass-through with ZFS and see if the Windows installer can see the partition, but I really doubt this is possible. Windows does not have ZFS support natively, but there are open-source projects that may allow it. Either way, you'll need to install drivers during Windows setup. I wish you luck.

Comment: Thank you I will look more into this, but I think I read that windows could not boot on OpenZFS, but I think I also read that windows could handle some LVM? But I'm not sure, especially how to passthrough it .
I will post an answer if I find a way to make this work.
I also though of maybe faking a normal drive via kvm/qemu if possible?